# Adview crash my app

Tags: android

note:before i add the ads my app was working good,with the same method

when i tried to add adview to my app it makes my app crash,so i delete it but still give me this
this is logcat

> 10-12 21:33:19.765 4993-4993/com.fm360.almorfis E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: com.fm360.almorfis, PID: 4993
>                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fm360.almorfis/com.fm360.almorfis.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setSelection(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setSelection(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                         at com.fm360.almorfis.MainActivity.spinnerVal(MainActivity.java:123)
>                                                                         at com.fm360.almorfis.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
>                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
>                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>   and this is my method where it tells

```
private void spinnerVal(int spinnerID, int move, int selection){
    Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(spinnerID);
    ArrayList<Integer> spinnerOption = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i+=move) {
        spinnerOption.add(i);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> integerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerOption);
    integerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(integerArrayAdapter);
    sp.setSelection(selection);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ArrayList<String> spinnerOption = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i+=move) {
    spinnerOption.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
```